# Как сделать запись в 1 строку файла c#

Tags: c#

нужно сделать так чтобы заменялся не весь файл а определённая строка

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в любом языке программирования: читаете файл порциями, и сразу же записываете в другой файл, находу меняя то, что требуется изменить. потом удаляете старый файл и переименовываете новый.

Answer (score 3):

Если файл не большой, то подойдёт примитивный способ:

```
using System.IO;

string text = File.ReadAllText("foobar.txt");
text = text.Replace("old_text", "new_text");
File.WriteAllText("foobar.txt", text);
```

Этот способ жрёт много памяти. Лучше делать таким способом (его реализация будет неплохой практикой для новичка):

1. Создаём новый файл.
2. Копируем в него часть исходного файла **до начала** заменяемой строки.
3. Записываем в него строку, которую хотим вставить.
4. Копируем в него остальную часть исходного файла **от конца** заменяемой строки.
5. Переименовываем исходный файл, например, добавив префикс old к названию.
6. Переименовываем новый файл именем исходного.
7. Удаляем исходный файл. **Этот пункт реализуй только когда протестируешь корректную работу алгоритма по остальным пунктам!**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О, картинка это хорошо, люблю поясняющие картинки, лайк! )